# Чем отличаются расширения java и jar?

Tags: java, файлы, jar

Чем отличаются расширения `.java` и `.jar` ?

Comment: .jar - это пакет. Например, Java-библиотека может быть оформлена в виде .jar файла, который по сути является архивом и содержит в себе Java-классы, файл манифеста и прочее.

Comment: Обязательно ли менять расширение с .java на .jar ?

Comment: @Николай тебе ниже ответ дали. В чем разница. файл .java не надо переименовывать в .jar

Comment: @Николай файл с расширением .java это просто исходный код. Т.е. это полуфабрикат, а не конечный продукт. Конечный продукт может иметь расширение .class, такой файл уже можно запустить. Если классов много, то можно упаковать их пакет.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Файлы с расширением .java - исходники классов, .class - скомпилированные в байткоды классы, .jar - это обычный архив, типо zip, только как бы джавовский.

Answer (score 0):

Java это исходный код программы, а jar архив в котором хранится папка META-INF и ваш пакет в котором находится байт-код (классы) а так-же прочие файлы.